# Switch desktop workspaces on secondary display only

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell

I use multiple firefox windows spread on different workspaces and i want to be able to switch the workspaces only on the second display.

I tried changing my external monitor to primary and selecting in tweak "Workspaces on primary display only" which actually works, but the problem is that window switcher(alt+tab) and the top bar are located on the external monitor.

Is there any other way where i can span workspaces only on the external monitor?

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using my laptop's monitor as a primary. It shows the system top bar and windows switcher (alt+tab) and that's great. But I use a secondary monitor to record screencasts and I want to use workspaces only on that monitor. I don't want the primary monitor to handle workspaces because I use it solely for utility apps that I need to make screencasts. Right now my solution is to mark those apps on the primary screen as "Always on visible workspace" but it would be much easier to just have workspaces disabled and the primary screen and enable them solely on a secondary monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If u check `tweaks` -> `Work space`, there's an option `Workspaces on primary display only`. I think if u set the monitor to the primary monitor, It might work as the way how u wanted

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks but I already mentioned that i tried this step. The problem is that the window switcher(alt+tab) and the top bar are located on the external monitor.